# iniファイル内でループ処理を記述したい

Tags: python, uwsgi

・下記で数字部分をループで簡潔に書きたいのですが、何か良い方法はありますか？

**emperor.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /var/hoge/1
emperor = /var/hoge/2
emperor = /var/hoge/3
emperor = /var/hoge/4
emperor = /var/hoge/5
emperor = /var/hoge/6
```

Comment: forループのようなものを想定しているのかもしれませんが、一般的にiniファイルは単純なテキストであり「プログラム言語」ではありません。まずは仕様を確認してください。 http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html

Comment: @re9 タグに python とついていますが、これは Python に関係するご質問なのでしょうか？　ひとまず .ini ファイル全般に言える回答をしましたが、何か特定のユースケースを想定なさっているのでしたら、その旨追記頂ければと思います。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 本文のファイル名や過去質問から察するに`uWSGI`の質問だと思われます。Pythonも一応は関連がありますが「iniファイルをPythonでパースしたい」等でもない限り、タグ付けにあまり意味はないかなと。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずは Wikipedia の [INI ファイル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB)の項目をお読みください ([英語版](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file)も詳しいです)。多くの場合 .ini ファイルは単に設定用のテキストファイルであり、ループや条件分岐などの制御構造は持ちません。よって .ini ファイルの中でループを実現することも、通常は行えません。

ただしお使いのアプリケーションによっては .ini ファイル内でループを実現できるように独自拡張している場合があるかもしれないので、まずは今お使いのアプリケーションで .ini ファイルがどのように解釈されることになっているのかの仕様等をご確認ください。